# Type Issue in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I must write a function which "un-nests" a list.

Example:
input [7,[[8]],[[5,[9]]],6] -> output (1,7),(3,8),(3,5),(4,9),(1,6)

I have the function, but I can't use it because a type problem.

**The function**

```
datatype 'a superList = Elem of 'a
                    |   List of 'a superList list;


local
fun un_nested( [] , n ) = []
 | un_nested( (Elem x)::xs, n ) = (n, x) :: un_nested( xs, n )
 | un_nested( (List x)::xs, n ) = un_nested( x, n + 1) @ un_nested(xs, n)

in
fun flat list = un_nested(list, 1)  
end;
```

**The example**

```
val test = List[List[Elem 2, List[Elem 3]]];
flat(test);
```

**The error**

```
datatype 'a superList = Elem of 'a | List of 'a superList list
val flat = fn : 'a superList list -> (int * 'a) list
val test = List [List [Elem #,List #]] : int superList
superList.SML:16.1-16.11 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: 'Z superList list
  operand:         int superList
  in expression:
    flat test

uncaught exception Error
  raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-296.20
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Your function accepts an array of superList values, but you're trying to pass just one value.

Here is an example that uses high-level List functions:

```
datatype 'a superList = Elem of 'a
                |   List of 'a superList list;

local
fun un_nested( Elem x , n ) = [(n, x)]
 | un_nested( List x, n ) = List.concat (List.map (fn e => un_nested(e, n + 1)) x)

in
fun flat list = un_nested(list, 1)  
end;
```

If you don't want to use high-level functions (I don't know the reasons for that), you can do it like this:

```
datatype 'a superList = Elem of 'a
                    |   List of 'a superList list;

local
fun un_nested( Elem x , n ) = [(n, x)]
 | un_nested( List [], n ) = []
 | un_nested( List (x::xs), n ) = un_nested(x, n + 1) @ un_nested(List xs, n)

in
fun flat list = un_nested(list, 1)  
end;
```